# Comparison between pointer and integer error

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I've got the following line of code in one of my Objective-C methods:

```
if (self.rule.sunday == YES) { do some stuff... }
```

The line produces the following compiler warning:

```
Comparison between pointer and integer
```

It's just a warning, so it's not life-threatening, but it's driving me nuts. Clearly there is some basic concept about integers, pointers, and/or booleans that I am missing. Can somebody please enlighten me so I can fix my code?

As usual, thanks in advance for your help.

UPDATE: For reference, the corrected code looks like this:

```
if ([self.rule.sunday boolValue] == YES) { do some stuf... }
```

Comment: Is `self.rule.sunday` a pointer?

Comment: If it is, that indicates something is horribly wrong in the design. Maybe in the implementation too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.rule.sunday` is returning an object reference.  `YES` is not an object, it's an `unsigned char`.  So you're comparing an object reference (ie, a memory address) to `1`.  Of course it's going to complain at you.

Comment: Ok...but if the object being referred to is a boolean, how are you supposed to compare against it for decision-making purposes? The construct I'm shooting for is, "If the boolean 'sunday' attribute of the Rule entity called 'rule' is 'yes' then do some stuff."

Comment: @Andy there is no such thing as a boolean object (unless you've created one).  BOOLs are commonly wrapped in `NSNumber` objects, so in  that case you'd use `-boolValue` to extract the `BOOL`.  But a better question is: how are you declaring the `sunday` property on the `rule` type?

Comment: I'm using Core Data to manage the objects; the "sunday" attribute is marked as a "Boolean."

While I was waiting I came across the NSNumber Class reference and the -boolValue and +numberWithBool methods. Substituting those on the lines in question took care of all of the compiler warnings, and eliminated another bug that I hadn't even started working on yet.

Thanks for the shove in the right direction, Dave.

Comment: @Andy yep, that makes sense.  I think the easiest way to fix this would be `if ([self.rule.sunday boolValue] == YES) { ... }`, since that means you won't have to be creating a ton of `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]` objects.  Glad I could help! :)

Comment: That's exactly how I did it. The only places I used the numberWithBool method was where a slice of code needed to update the 'sunday' attribute. Thanks again.